# Firestore: How to order by dynamic keys

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a program in Angular/Firestore that will allow users to create forms with questions, (similar to typeform) and then other people can fill out those questions.

The issue I'm having is that admin needs to be able to filter by the dynamically created question answer values.

Here is an example of the data structure:

Form collection:

```js
{
   id: 123,
   questions: [
       {
          id: 0,
          value: "How many students did you teach today?"
       },
       {
          id: 1,
          value: "What school were you at?"
       },
       {
          id: 2,
          value: "What was the date?"
       },
   ]
}
```

UserSubmissions

```js
{
    formId: 123,
    questions: [
      {
         id: 0,
         value: 10
      },
      {
         id: 1,
         value: 'Random school name'
      },
      {
         id: 2,
         value: 2021/07/12
      },
    ]
}
```

So let's say we had 100 form submissions and admin wanted to order by how many students were taught, how could I do something like `.orderBy("formSubmissions.questions[0].value")` or `.orderBy(formSubmissions.questions.0.value")`.

The second one works, but there would need to be a composite index created for an unknown amount of questions. I could technically have it so you can only order by the first 10 questions or something but I feel like there has to be a better way to doing this. I don't mind restructuring data if I have to.

Comment: Hi @Colin! Would you mind sharing more details about how do you plan on doing the filtering/sorting? A code sample on how you use the `orderBy` function would be great.

Comment: The issue is I'm not sure how to do the filtering/sorting. Something like "query.where("formId","==",123).orderBy('questions.0.value',"desc");" would be great but I'm not sure if it's possible. I just want to order by a column but the "key" is created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order on specific questions, consider creating a subcollection of questions under each form submission. Trying to order/filter on specific array elements is going to either be difficult, not scale beyond 10 items, or both.

Comment: If I were to create a subcollection of questions, what would the query look like? I would need to get all questions where formId = 123, but only order by questions where id= 0 if that makes sense.